# Not all JComponents being painted

Tags: java, swing

I have two objects that extent JComponent, both of these override paintComponent(). When just one or the other is added to a Jpanel it is painted correctly however if I add both only one is shown.

My init method that added both is below:

```
public class Applet extends JApplet {

long time_interval = 200; // length of time between moves in ms
int w = 75;
int h = 75;
int[][] a = new int[w][h]; // creates a 2D array to use as background
Creature test;

public void init() {
    System.out.println("Zachary Powell 1104583");
    resize(750, 850);

    WorldView tv = new WorldView(a);
    // add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    test = new Creature(100, 30, 1);
    add(tv);
    add(test);

    startTimer();
}
...
```

However tv is not drawn

my Creature class:

```
public class Creature extends JComponent{
    int health;
    boolean dead;
    int xpos, ypos;
    static int size = 10;

    Creature(int h, int y, int x) {
        dead = false;
        health = h;
        ypos = y;
        xpos = x;
    }

    void Update() {
        checkHealth();
    }

    private void checkHealth() {
        if (health <= 0)
            dead = true;
    }

    public void reduceHealth(int amount) {
        health -= amount;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (xpos < 75) {
            xpos++;
        } else {
            xpos = 1;
        }
        reduceHealth(1);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fill3DRect(xpos * size, ypos * size, size, size, true);
    }
}
```

And my WorldView class

```
public class WorldView extends JComponent {
    static Color[] colors =
            {black, green, blue, red,
                    yellow, magenta, pink, cyan};
    int[][] a;
    int w, h;
    static int size = 10;
    //Create the object with the array give
    public WorldView(int[][] a) {
        this.a = a;
        w = a.length;
        h = a[0].length;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                    g.fill3DRect(i * size, j * size,
                            size, size, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(w * size, h * size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `JApplet` when your class is already a `JApplet`?

Comment: Yes it was messy to say the least, have now cleaned up @peeskillet however still same issue

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) An applet should not attempt to set its own size.

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for top level containers is a BorderLayout. By default, if you don't specify a constraint the component is added to the CENTER. However only one component can be added to the CENTER so only the last one added is displayed.

> WorldView should be in the backround centred with Creature in the foreground

Then add WorldView to the applet and add the Creature to the WorldView.

You will need to use appropriate layout manager on the WorldView to get your desired layout.

Comment: ah ok, however should I add my JComponents then, WorldView should be in the backround centred with Creature in the foreground

Comment: @ZacPowell, see additional info.